# Closing all tabs of a specific website using Chrome's JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to use Chrome's JavaScript Console to close all tabs for a specific website or a URL/title regex - e.g. closing dozens of Stackoverflow tabs that are using up memory instead of close them one by one?

Comment: I wouldn't think this'd be possible using the JS console, since that's sandboxed to each web page and would pose a security risk if it could access top-level browser elements. You could do this using the Chrome Extensions API though (here are the docs specific to working with tabs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do with the JavaScript console. The JavaScript console has no way of interacting with the browser in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this and it seems to work in Chrome.  Although it does mean that you have to programmatically open the window as well:

```
mywindow = window.open('', 'windowName', '', true);
```

then you close it with:

```
mywindow.close();
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14636251/377856).  Basically you need a reference to do what you're doing.  You can't find by title or URL.