# window.open is not opening again in the same window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time a specific page reloads, a popup window is opened to a google search of what is contained in the 2nd . The issue is that it keeps opening in a new window instead of inside the original popup.

```
var td_name = $("td:eq(1)");
var td_text = td_name.text();
window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+td_text+"", "myWindow", '_blank');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser security model has prevented that for a while (understandably).  It will work if the "reload" is done with JS and not a full browser refresh.

See this related answer for a workaround using window references:

> No. Without a reference to the window, you can't find it again, by
>   name or otherwise. There is no collection of windows.
>
> **UPDATE:** Here's how you could do it yourself:
>
> ```
> var windows = {};
> function openWindow(url, name, features) {
>     windows[name] = window.open(url, name, features);
>     return windows[name];
> }
> ```
>
> Now, `openWindow` will always open the window, and if the window
>   already exists, it will load the given URL in that window and return a
>   reference to that window. Now you can also implement `findWindow`:
>
> ```
> function findWindow(name) {
>     return windows[name];
> }
> ```
>
> Which will return the window if it exists, or `undefined`.
>
> You should also have `closeWindow`, so you don't keep references to
>   windows that you opened yourself:
>
> ```
> function closeWindow(name) {
>     var window = windows[name];
>     if(window) {
>         window.close();
>         delete windows[name];
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> > If it is not possible, what is the point giving windows names?
>
> The name is used internally by the browser to manage windows. If you
>   call `window.open` with the same name, it won't open a new window but
>   instead load the URL into the previously opened window. There are a
>   few more things, from [MDN
>   window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open):
>
> > If a window with the name strWindowName already exists, then strUrl is loaded into the existing window. In this case the return value of
> >     the method is the existing window and strWindowFeatures is ignored.
> >     Providing an empty string for strUrl is a way to get a reference to an
> >     open window by its name without changing the window's location. To
> >     open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special
> >     value _blank for strWindowName.
>
> **SOURCE:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364899

Comment: This seems to be gong way over my head for some reason. Would the correct format now be this? It is not working for me. `var windows = {};
function openWindow("http://www.google.com/search?q="+td_text+"", "myWindow", '_blank') {
    windows[myWindow] = window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+td_text+"", "myWindow", '_blank');
    return windows[myWindow];
}`

Comment: @BrandonHellman the answer I have cited there won't work around full page refreshes.  There isn't a solution for that that I know of.  I think it is intentionally impossible for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       function openWindow(td_text)
                {

                   var strurl ="http://www.google.com/search?q="+td_text;               

 window.open(strurl,"mywindow","menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=550,height=200");
                }
        var td_name = $("td:eq(1)");
        var td_text = td_name.text();
        openWindow(td_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
window.open(url,"_self");
```

then it will open in the same window.